# C# read txt file and store the data in formatted array

Tags: c#

I have a text file which contains following

```
Name address phone        salary
Jack Boston  923-433-666  10000
```

all the fields are delimited by the spaces.

I am trying to write a C# program, this program should read a this text file and then store it in the formatted array.

My Array is as follows:

```
address
salary
```

When ever I am trying to look in google I get is how to read and write a text file in C#.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Where are you confused? What have you tried? The hardest part would probably loading the file.

Comment: If you have control over it, I don't think spaces make for a great delimiter. You might want to change that.

Comment: I am able to read the file but not sure about loading...because for loading the file I want 2nd (address) and fourth field (salary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use File.ReadAllLines method to load the file into an array.  You can then use a for loop to loop through the lines, and the string type's Split method to separate each line into another array, and store the values in your formatted array.

Something like:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var fields = lines[i].Split(' ');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Helpful, Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 3):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Can use for example [fast csv reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) where you can specify a `delimeter` you need.

There are plenty others on internet like that, just search and pick that one which fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you don't know how much whitespace is between each string in a given line.

```
// Method to split a line into a string array separated by whitespace
private string[] Splitter(string input)
{
    return Regex.Split(intput, @"\W+");
}


// Another code snippet to  read the file and break the lines into arrays 
// of strings and store the arrays in a list.
List<String[]> arrayList = new List<String[]>();

using (FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.txt"))
{
    using(TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fStream))
    {
        string line = "";
        while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line = reader.ReadLine()))
        {
            arrayList.Add(Splitter(line));
        }
    }
}
```