# Loading richTextBox text into an array

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a following question, as I am just starting to learn C#.

I have a class defined like this:

```
public class Piksel
    {
        public int r;
        public int g;
        public int b;
    }
```

I then declare an array like so:

```
Piksel[,] tab2 = new Piksel[32, 32];
```

Now, I have a *.txt file in the following format:

```
...

X: 15 , Y: 2 , R: 255 , G: 255 , B: 255

X: 16 , Y: 2 , R: 183 , G: 183 , B: 183

X: 17 , Y: 2 , R: 32 , G: 32 , B: 32

X: 18 , Y: 2 , R: 32 , G: 32 , B: 32

X: 19 , Y: 2 , R: 159 , G: 159 , B: 159

X: 20 , Y: 2 , R: 255 , G: 255 , B: 255

...
```

I load it into a richTextBox:

```
 OpenFileDialog openF1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openF1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Nagash\\Desktop";
        openF1.Title = "Wybierz plik z danymi obrazka";
        openF1.DefaultExt = "*txt";
        openF1.Filter = "Pliki TXT|*txt";

        if (openF1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && openF1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            richTextBox3.LoadFile(openF1.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
```

And now my question: how can I put that data in the tab2 array from the richTextBox. For example, if a line in richTextBox reads

```
X: 15 , Y: 2 , R: 255 , G: 255 , B: 255
```

then what i want is the following result:

```
tab2[15,2].r=255 tab[15,2].g=255 tab[15,2].b=255
```

I treid fiddling with regular expressions like so:

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(richTextBox3.Text, "[0-9]+");
        foreach (Match str in mc)
            richTextBox1.Text= richTextBox1.Text + Convert.ToString(str);
```

But then I am unsure how to tell if a number is 255 or is it 25 and a 5. Also still unsure how to put it into the array.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you win from loading the text into a textbox, but whereever you take the text from that you want to process, you are probably best off if you do the processing in a series of steps:

First, Split the text into rows (since seemingly one row corresponds to one pixel)

```
var rows = text.Split("\r\n"); // Or only \r, whatever fits
```

Then, Parse each row and create an intermediate object of the form `{ int X; int Y; int R; int G; int B; }`. Or you use a dictionary for each row.

```
var inputs = rows.Select(r => Parse(r));
```

Finally, Iterate through the newly created objects and process each.

```
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Piksel[input['X'], input['Y']] = new Piksel { r = input['R'], g = input['G'], b = input['B'] };
}
```

This boils your question down to as how to parse a line of the following form

```
X: 15 , Y: 2 , R: 255 , G: 255 , B: 255
```

into a dictionary with values for each X, Y, R, G, and B. This can be the proper place to apply regular expressions. Or you use `Split` again:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> Parse(string row)
{
    var keysAndValues= row.Split(',');
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (var keyValue in keysAndValues)
    {
        var parts = value.Split(':');
        var key = parts[0];
        var value = int.Parse(parts[1]);

        dict[key] = value;
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the great explanation. I don't "win" anything by putting that text in the rTB, it's just a program I do for my class, and one of the requirements is loading txt file into rTB, so i tohught why not do it while doing other thing already.

I don't really understand your code now yet, but will read on the commands you used. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3706568 - Got it.

Comment: Just one question, what is r in your code, a variable? And if so, which one?

Comment: @NagashTDN: `r => Parse(r)` is a [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). It defines a function with one parameter named `r` which is a short for "row". The type `string` is automatically deduced because you execute `Select` on a collection of strings. `Select` iterates through the string array (that is, through the rows of the text), and for each row it calls `Parse`, passing the row as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can just save your file like this :

15 , 2 , 255 , 255 , 255

and use this function to separate the values:

```
  static  IEnumerable<string> LineSplitter(string line)
        {
            int fieldStart = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                if (line[i] == ',')
                {
                    yield return line.Substring(fieldStart, i - fieldStart);
                    fieldStart = i + 1;
                }
                if (line[i] == '"')
                    for (i++; line[i] != '"'; i++) { }
            }

        }
```

And to convert these values to an array use this :

```
 IEnumerable<string>  res= LineSplitter(theString);
                  string[] array = res.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

It's an example you should change it .

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. However, I need my text file to be in that exact format, wtih the letters and ":". Is there any way to rewrite the function you provided to include that formatting?

Comment: Yes, as you can see every **char** in the string is checked ,you can rewrite it.

Comment: take a look :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777206/c-sharp-read-txt-file-and-store-the-data-in-formatted-array